# Unable to access network file from ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to access a network file from the SSRS report.

Below is what I have tried or done

- Included a table in the new report
- On one of the column box  clicked the
  text box properties ----->Action ---->Go to URL ------ Here I  gave the fully  qualified server name  file://Servername/xxxx

Now I deployed the report on to  the SSRS server  and when I click on the particular col nothing happens (I am  testing this on 2016 version of ssrs)

When I deployed the same report on 2008 version of ssrs  I was able to read/open the file from the network location

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

make sure the service account that is used to run the SSRS 2016 version has access to read from the location you are referencing

Comment: I did make sure  ..it has read permissions ... But  still the problem  persists.